Ubuntu 23.10 stucked at startup menu screen
I have Ubuntu 23.04, after upgrading to ubuntu 23.10 get stucked. See the attached image for detail
I tried all menu but it did not work.
I have Ubuntu dual boot vs Windows. It works with ubuntu 23.04
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
